# How to keep header names after running for loop

Tags: r, tidyverse

The following script produces median values of every column of mtcars dataset but without header names. How can I keep the header names after running a for loop on a dataframe?

```
output_mtcars <- vector("double", ncol(mtcars))
for(i in seq_along(mtcars)) {
  output_mtcars[[i]] <- mean(mtcars[[i]])
}
```

Comment: any reprex data?

Comment: mtcars comes with tidyverse package @nycrefugee

Comment: you're quite right @user1883491

Comment: does it have to be a loop?

Comment: @user1883491 `mtcars` comes with vanilla `R` no need to load the `tidyverse` or other packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use a loop you could use `setNames()`:

```
output_mtcars <- setNames(vector("double", ncol(mtcars)), names(mtcars))
for (i in seq_along(mtcars)) {
  output_mtcars[[i]] <- mean(mtcars[[i]])
}

output_mtcars
#       mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec         vs         am       gear       carb 
# 20.090625   6.187500 230.721875 146.687500   3.596563   3.217250  17.848750   0.437500   0.406250   3.687500   2.812500
```

Answer (score 4):

Both base R `sapply` and `purrr::map_dbl` will preserve names here:

```
sapply(mtcars, mean)
purrr::map_dbl(mtcars, mean)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a list instead of a vector we can achieve this in the loop:

```
output_mtcars <- list("double", ncol(mtcars))
for(i in seq_along(mtcars)) {
  output_mtcars[[i]] <- mean(mtcars[[i]])
  names(output_mtcars[[i]]) <- names(mtcars[i])
}

> output_mtcars
[[1]]
     mpg 
20.09062 

[[2]]
   cyl 
6.1875 

[[3]]
    disp 
230.7219 

[[4]]
      hp 
146.6875 

[[5]]
    drat 
3.596563 

....
```

Or you can just rename the vector after the loop:

```
output_mtcars <- vector("double")
for(i in seq_along(mtcars)) {
  output_mtcars[[i]] <- mean(mtcars[[i]])
}

names(output_mtcars)<-names(mtcars)

> output_mtcars
       mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec 
 20.090625   6.187500 230.721875 146.687500   3.596563   3.217250  17.848750 
        vs         am       gear       carb 
  0.437500   0.406250   3.687500   2.812500
```

Comment: ...or name them before the loop when you create `output_mtcars`. `setNames()` is another useful option here.